# Cannot resolve symbole 'input' JAVA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, while-loop

so I want to do a little alround program with quiz etc (won't paste the entire code because its 300 lines of basic stuff), and I want a boolean that repeats a gambling game for me, so when I get to the line:

```
String PlayAgain = input.nextLine();
```

I get the error: Cannot resolve symbole 'input'.

The code for the little game is here:

```
enter  boolean InGame = true;
        while (InGame == true);

        System.out.println("Glückspiel: Wer näher an der zufälligen Zahl ist gewinnt! 1-100");
        System.out.println("Spieler Eins");
        double playerOne = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Spieler Zwei");
        double playerTwo = scan.nextDouble();

        double randomValue = Math.random() * 100.0;

        // Math.abs() ist eine Methode die den Betrag einer Zahl zurueck gibt.
        double spacingOne = Math.abs(playerOne - randomValue);
        double spacingTwo = Math.abs(playerTwo - randomValue);
        System.out.println("Die Random Zahl war " + randomValue);

        if (spacingOne < spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Spieler Eins hat gewonnen!");
        }

        if (spacingOne > spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen!");
        }

        if (spacingOne == spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Unentschieden!");
        }
        System.out.println("Wenn du nochmal spielen willst schreibe 'ja' wenn nicht 'nein'");
        String PlayAgain = input.nextLine();
        if  (PlayAgain == "Ja");
```

Can you help me?

Comment: where did you declare `input`? Try this:`String PlayAgain = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: please accept one of the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you miss

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` ?

or change `input` to `scan`

```
String PlayAgain = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `scan` looks like the one you use to store user's input. I suggest you to use this one.

Or to declare `Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in)` because I cannot see it in the code you posted